# parsing fairly complex but structure files in c++

Tags: c++, parsing, file-io

I'm trying to parse a fairly complicated, but structured file using c++.

```
011 FistName MiddleName LastName age(int) date(4/6/2001) position status ...
012 FistName MiddleName LastName age(int) date(4/6/2001) position status ...
...
```

That's what the file format looks like.
I'm trying to store the data as individual field of a struct but the first middle last name are of variable size and may not have the middle name in them, so how would you distinguish that?

For example,

```
014 Jon Smith ...
015 Jon J Smith, Jr. ...
```

I want to store the whole name in a name field rather than separate them.
Say we have

```
struct{
    std::string name;
    int id;
    int age;
    std::string position;
    ...

}
```

How would i go about parsing everything?

Comment: Scan the id number, scan for "age", everything in between is the name.

Comment: I'm fond of using Boost.Xpressive for this kind of thing.

Comment: @user315052: Not a great idea, according to henry hAGErty and others like him :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes, if you're using C++11, you could adapt the [std::regex match example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) to accomplish what you want.

If you're not, you should use [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html) to accomplish what you want.

Here's an example of a regular expression you could use:

```
^\d+ (\w+) ?(\w*) (\w+),? ?(\w+\.)? age\((\d+)\) date\((\d\/\d\/\d+)\) (\w+) (\w+)
```

To find out what that regular expression means and how it matches things, check out [this link](http://regexr.com?33kup).

To learn more about regular expressions, I'd highly recommend [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) by Jeffrey Friedl.

It would match the following:

```
014 Jon Smith age(32) date(4/6/2001) position status
014 Jon J Smith, Jr. age(16) date(4/6/2001) position status
015 FistName MiddleName LastName, Title. age(45) date(4/6/2001) position status
016 FistName MiddleName LastName age(7) date(4/6/2001) position status
039 FistName MiddleName LastName age(100) date(4/6/2001) position status
```

Comment: what kind of regular expression would I use to just parse the string though? I always have problems with them.

Comment: thank you for the update. i looked into regex and it took me a while to remember the stuff i learned in class plus internet tutorial, but i manage to parse the necessary information. Just wondering though, do you if it is better to call regex one on the whole string or multiple time to get the different pieces that you need? How big would the performance difference be?

Comment: You're welcome :) The only way to find out is to try both, while timing them. However, I'd say don't worry about performance until you have to. Keep the code as readable, simple and understandable as you can. Unless you find yourself waiting an unacceptable amount of time for the processing to complete, it really doesn't matter which way you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could simply use fstream and then take it 1 word at a time. First into an int, then into a string until the next value is an int (age). If i recall correctly from my infinite loops, doing a stream input to an int when the stream isnt a number doesnt take the value from the stream so you could do >> int, >> string >> int >> etc until you know you have the age.

etc etc. you get the point :)

PS: remember to use .get() and not .eof() for your input loops :)

Comment: the problem is that I won't know how long the string will be so I won't know when to stop parsing for string, and start parsing for int, right? or I'm I misunderstanding something here? cin>> string will stop after a space has been found right?

Comment: yeah it will. but the int will only get something if the value is an int (hence you might be able to test to see if int is getting something and if its not then your still getting names and not an age)

Comment: so if int is not getting any value, and i do cin>>string, i will get the previous value that was trying to be put into the int? or will it continue to parse the next string?